# Android Gradle exclude classes for Debug BuildType

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

**Bakground**

I am using Google Play Services in my project for various reasons. Google Play Services are a big dependancy which is drastically increases my build time. So I would like to disable Google Play Services for my "Debug" version , so I could compile my project faster.

**What I do ?**

To exclude Google Play Services during my debug builds , I just do the conditional compilation like this :

```
releaseCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.+'
releaseCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.+'
releaseCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.+'
```

So Google Play Services are being compiled only for release builds , and not included in Debug builds.So far so good.

**A pitfall**

There are some classes in my code that are dependent on Google Play Services.I can easily abstract them with interfaces , and load stubs instead.But the problem is , those classes are still being compiled during my "Debug" build even though I am not referencing them directly (in fact I am loading them using reflection).

**Workaround**

To ignore compilation errors for classes I am not using ,I just exclude them from source sets in debug build type like this :

```
   debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        sourceSets {
            main {
                java {
                    exclude '**/tracking/impl/**'
                    exclude '**/GoogleApiClientWrapper.java'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the problem is solved , I am able to compile by "Debug" version without Google play services and the build time is faster.

**The problem**

Even though I am specifying the *sourceSets* block only in the "Debug" build type , I have noticed that those classes are stripped anyway even in release build Types. Why ? How can I exclude those classes **ONLY** for Debug build type ?

**NOTE**

- Already configured proguard-rules to not strip those classes (since I am using reflection)
- Disabled proguard for release build
- Tried to define source sets in different places (even in flavors) , it looks like the latest sourceSet defined overrides all the previous.

Comment: "Why?" -- because `sourcesets` does not affect an individual build type. I'm surprised your Gradle script runs. I would expect a DSL error for not finding a `sourcesets` method on the `debug` object. "How can I exclude those classes ONLY for Debug build type ?" -- put them in the `release` sourceset and get rid of them from `main`. "it looks like the latest sourceSet defined overrides all the previous" -- I have no idea what "the latest sourceSet" means.

Comment: Enlightening ! If you could just point out how exactly I put them into "release sourceset " ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to have Java classes that are unique to some build type or product flavor, put them in a sourceset for that build type or product flavor.

If you have a typical Gradle for Android project structure, somewhere, you have `src/main/java/`, with Java classes in there in appropriate directories based upon package name. Those classes, being in the `main` sourceset, are used for all builds.

If you want to have classes are are only used in a `release` build, create a `src/release/java/` directory, and move those classes from `src/main/java/` to `src/release/java/`.

In a `debug` build, the `release` classes are ignored. In a `release` build, the `release` classes are used.

Note that you cannot use this technique to *replace* classes in `main`. So, you cannot have `com.ivelius.awesomeapp.Foo` in `main` and another `com.ivelius.awesomeapp.Foo` in `release` — you will get some form of "duplicate class" error.

Comment: Awesome ! Just didn't realize I can also create a "release" folder in the same way as every flavor folder created.Thanks :)

Comment: @Ivelius: Yup, you can create sourcesets for any build type, any product flavor, and (IIRC) any build variant (e.g., `releaseVanilla` for a combination of `release` build type and `vanilla` product flavor).